# ClassNotFoundException:KahaPersistenceAdapter in ACtiveMQ 5.8

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

I migrated my application from `ActiveMQ 5.5.1` to `ActiveMQ 5.8.0`. 
My application has persistence configuration at `activemq.xml` file as following:

```
    <persistenceAdapter>
     <kahaPersistenceAdapter directory="${activemq.base}/data/msg" maxDataFileLength="20 Mb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>
```

but when I start activemq, I get following exception at `wrapper.log` file:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/24 10:43:28 | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.store.kahadaptor.KahaPersistenceAdapter
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/24 10:43:28 |   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/24 10:43:28 |   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/24 10:43:28 |   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/24 10:43:28 |   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/24 10:43:28 |   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/24 10:43:28 |   at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanQNameHelper.loadClass(XBeanQNameHelper.java:107)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/24 10:43:28 |   at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanQNameHelper.getBeanInfo(XBeanQNameHelper.java:72)
```

Note: My application has message in queues that stored by `activemq 5.5.1` and can't change persistence configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had you put `activemq-all-5.8.0.jar` in the classpath?

The `KahaPersistenceAdapter` is [deprecated](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4125?page=com.atlassian.jirafisheyeplugin%3afisheye-issuepanel), but it is still contained in the jar.

Comment: @Tim Bish: Thanks. I put `activemq-all-5.8.0.jar` in classpath and correct my issue but another exception throwed:`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.http.security.Constraint`

Comment: Could your provide the full stack trace? It looks like you have a broken dependency on jetty jars.

Comment: solved :), I replaced `jetty.xml` file at `activemq 5.8` with `activemq 5.5`, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In v5.8.0 the dependencies have been broken apart a bit to allow you to shrink the amount of jars you need to pull in just to run a Broker.  The Kaha adapter is located within the activemq-amq-store component so you need to bring that into your project if you want to use it.

Note that this adapter is deprecated and will be gone in v5.9.0 so its a good idea to move to one of the supported one's.  Currently the default adapter is KahaDB and is located in the activemq-kahadb-store.  You could also try the LevelDB adapter which has a faster index but is still young and might have some issues.

While there's no migration tools that will easily allow you to move from the older store to the newer KahaDB store you can do this by setting up a new broker with KahaDB and connect it using network connector to the old one. The mew broker should drain all messages and store them in the KahaDB store once the new broker registers demand for the destinations you have Messages on in the older store on your old broker.